# Vertical Overflow Into Footer With Embedded Forum Object In Body

Tags: html, css, overflow, embed, forum

We're implementing a Muut forum in our site, and have successfully embedded it into a coding block in the body of the page.  However, when logged in as an admin, the sidebar of the forum takes on additional features that pushes the forum into the footer of the page, instead of the body stretching to accommodate the forum dynamically.  We've tried different coding techniques but have settled on a static page length (for now).  We'd like to implement a way to dynamically stretch the page to fit the forum, no matter the size, vertically.

Here's the header we implemented:

```
<style>
#pageWrapper {
min-height: 1100px; }
</style>
```

And here's the muut embedded script:

```
<!-- Muut placeholder tag -->
<div class="muut">

<!-- Muut API -->
<a class="muut-url" href="https://muut.com/i/ourforumid">Our Forum</a>

<!-- Custom HTML -->
<h4><a href="#Another Forum 1">Another Forum</a></h4>
<h4><a href="#Another Forum 2">Another Forum</a></h4>

<script src="//cdn.muut.com/1/moot.min.js"></script>

</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as our conventional attempts with div styling haven't worked.  We don't want to overflow with a scrollbar, or hide the overflow, but just want the body container to stretch dynamically to accommodate the forum.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Muut has its own div call tags, so after speaking with their team, here's the correct implementation:

```
  .muut .m-sidebar {
    position: relative;
  }
```

It's that simple.